# The symbol does not match

Tags: eosio.token, transfer

Token transfer between 2 accounts give me this error. token transfer works though if one of the account is the token contract account. how do i fix this?

```
  "details": [
      {
        "message": "assertion failure with message: The symbol does not match",
        "file": "wasm_interface.cpp",
        "line_number": 964,
        "method": "eosio_assert"
      },
      {
        "message": "pending console output: ",
        "file": "apply_context.cpp",
        "line_number": 113,
        "method": "exec_one"
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably are sending the symbol wrong. It should look like this if you are using cleos:

```
cleos push action eosio.token transfer '[ "bob", "alice", "50.0000 SYS", "m" ]' -p bob@active
```

where eosio.token is the contract account, bob and alice are accounts, "SYS" is the token and "m" is a memo message. Also, do not forget to import the keys into your wallet and unlock it.

Maybe you share a code sample or command of how you execute the action, so I can help you more precisely.

Comment: i don't get this error any more.